# uiscrollview's unusual contentsize property

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am quite new to iOS application development.

I was working with `UIScrollView` and found very strange behavior. Hope somebody could explain this to me.

I tried the two methods and found the outputs different.

1). `UIScrollView` is added to my `view` in the Interface Builder, and a `view (UIView)` is also added to the `scrollview` earlier. I set the view's bounds manually in the IB, and set the `scrollview`'s `content size` in the class file.

**Observation :** The `scrollview` doesn't `scroll` with the `setcontentsize`, rather takes some unusual `content size`, independent of anything else, even its own bounds.

2). The same `UIScrollView` is again added in the Interface Builder, but the `view` is added this time programmatically.

**Observation :** This time everything works out quite good.

I don't understand what could have gone wrong.

Can anyone explain and elaborate

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what your problem is, but if you want to be able to add views to a UIScrollView in IB, create a UIScrollView subclass and do something like this:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    CGRect bounds = CGRectZero;

    for (UIView* view in self.subviews)
    {
        bounds = CGRectUnion(bounds, view.frame);
    }

    [self setContentSize:bounds.size];
}
```

Comment: I'm using a storyboard, hence I have to write my initialisation code in viewDidLoad, where except for the self.view, all others objects from the interface builder have {{0,0},{0,0}} CGRect. Hence this is not useful. Also may I know what you did not understand in my question?